# Is reputation earned when the reputation limit expires?

Tags: support

Last night I reached the limit of 200 reputation points per day, that means I have to wait 24 hours (or something) to keep gaining reputation, but it turns out that before the 24 hours, someone votes one of my posts, this clearly does not generate reputation , however I would like to know, if when the 24 hours are fulfilled, those points of the votes in my posts will be awarded to me or will they simply be lost?

Comment: They are simply lost, as far as I know. Never been there myself, but the limit would need nothing if it were only delaying the votes.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier you should try it. It's awesome :)

Comment: I'd be set for quite a while if that were the case

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reputation points above 200 on a given day are lost (except for points gained from accepted answers). Those points will not be retroactively applied in the next 24 hour period. When that clock resets at UTC 0:00, you'll start gaining reputation again, but only with new upvotes.

Answer (score 7):

You don't get them.

The rep cap is per UTC day. So, when the next UTC day starts after you hit the cap, you'll start gaining rep from upvotes and such again. But the previous votes are not held in a pool- That would defeat the purpose of the cap.

Any rep you gain from the non-exempt methods is just 0 until the next UTC day.

If something happens down the road, such as a post deletion, to recalculate your rep, then the rep you gained for that day may change, and the votes that counted for that day may change. Short of that, however, nothing will make those votes count for rep.

Answer (score 2):

You don't receive delayed rep. Upvotes received when you're rep-capped just don't give you rep.

Answer (score 2):

Those reputation points are essentially lost.

I find it useful to keep 'Epic' or 'Legendary' badges as 'next badge' on your Activity page, because if you click on them, you can see how many points you can still earn this day by simple upvotes. If you notice early in the day that you will probably lose more than 50 rep-points because of the rep-cap, you can use the points for a bounty (on your own, or on someone else's question). That's the only way I'm aware of of how not to "lose" those points completely.

(Well, actually... If you are keeping a list of really bad answers, you can go and use the extraneous points on downvoting the bad answers. But who would do *that*, really? ;P )

Answer (score 1):

The points normally awarded for votes on your questions or answers are lost.

But the reputation cap applies *only* to votes on questions & answers. Not on bounties or accepted answers.

But all isn't lost:

- all votes you collected on your answers after the cap is effective still count for the tag badges awards.
- a very good question or answer (lots of votes, generally 8 votes) appears in the 10k tools (questions/answers with extreme votes), and may attract more upvotes the next day, and those will bring rep.
- more than 200 points per day counts for the "epic" and "legendary" badge, although you don't need rep. capping for that. 200 with accepted answers or bounties count.